# Can open a connection to a non-existing database, how is this possible?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, database, visual-studio-2013

I have desktop software. At login I test if the database can be reached by just opening the connection. If it can't it throws exception. If it can then all is good, I close the connection and go into the main window. Until here all is normal. In the mainwindow I have a thread that checks the connection from 1 to 1 minute by calling the isDbConnectionOk method below:

```
sqlConnString =  @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabasePath"] + ";Integrated Security=True";
sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString);



private bool isDbConnectionOk(string errorMessage)
{
    using (var l_oConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConn.ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            l_oConnection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
            {
                this.ShowMessageAsync("Waring", errorMessage);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I test this by inserting a USB stick with the database and connecting to it. When I'm in the mainwindow after the first check I unplug the stick and wait for the thread to check again. The connection is opened without any problem altough there is no database to connect to. Can someone please explain this? How in the world is it cacheing it or what is happening? How come for the login part it throws error if the database path is invalid or cannot be reached and in main window it keeps being able to open the connection when no database is present?

Comment: maybe you can add an attempt to access the database to your check of the connection (ask for the table names or something).  It might be lazily evaluating things and not checking the connection until it has to actually do something.

Comment: Yes but that would be much costly than just trying to open it, and besides, it works just fine at the login part when I do the checks. Why wouldn't it for the mainwindow too....

Comment: what checks do you do on login? would it open a connection if you changed the sqlConnString and kept the usb in?

Comment: Same check, trying to open the connection. I test it by trying to open when there's no usb and it can't open, then when I plug in usb it can connect to db. Also, yes, I can pick a copy of the db from the harddrive and it can also open it as expected  so no problems here :)

Comment: Well, if you check db access with a query at least you can eliminate the idea that it is actually connecting to a valid database somehow (on your hard drive perhaps).  Don't know much about C# so that's all I've got :)

Comment: Yes I know,the question tough isn't "how can I check for sure?" :P, I apreciate you answering tough.

Comment: Do you disconnect/eject the USB properly from windows or just simply unplug it? I would suggest adding another catch (Exception) {} to catch non SQL exceptions that may come from the operating system.

Comment: Do you have connection pooling on?

Comment: @SteveFerg "Unproperly" :), but now I tryed the proper way and it can't deconnect it cuz the database is in use. Also, before the method you see in the post I had a generic try-catch for any error type, still no luck.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Until the SQL connection is closed, the operating system will think there is still a file available (cached) whether it is physically connected or not.

Comment: @SteveFerg yes but I don't see how it is related to the problem. I did the SAME thing with the login part, connected usb, tested connection a few times, unplugged usb, tested again and it wasn't able to open it again.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen isn't that on by default?

Comment: When not ejected properly, the file system for that device is in an unknown state. There seems to be nothing wrong with your code per se, but the operating system will do what it will do as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

**Change `D:\Sample.mdf` with your file path**

```
 private string _connectionString =
        @"Data Source =(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDBFileName=D:\Sample.mdf;" +
        "Integrated Security=true";

    private bool IsDbConnectionOk(out string errorMessage)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    errorMessage = null;
                    return false;
                }
                errorMessage = null;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                errorMessage = exp.Message;
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void BtnTestConnection_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string errormessage;
        var isOk = IsDbConnectionOk(out errormessage);
        if (isOk)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Is OK");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection error : " + errormessage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tryed your code, same thing, it opens the connection even tough the usb is out. Also I don't see any significant changes in the code besides catching a general exception which I tryed b4. Thanx anyway.